# Sending an email with an attachement using MultiPartEmail

Tags: java, multipart

I'm trying to use this method to send an email with the attached `hello.json` file. But when I build and run the code, the email gets sent, but the attachement never makes it with the email. Is there anything special about the MultPartEmail API that I'm missing? I've based my code on other examples.

```
public void sendNotification(String from, String pass, String host, int port, String[] to,
  String subject, String body) throws EmailException {
    log.trace("Beginning sendNotification function");

    EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
    attachment.setPath("C:/temp/hello.json");
    attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
    attachment.setName("user");
    attachment.setDescription("external json file");

    File f = new File("C:/temp/hello.json");

    MultiPartEmail gmail = new MultiPartEmail();
    gmail.setSmtpPort(port);
    gmail.setHostName(host);
    gmail.setAuthentication(from, pass);
    gmail.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    gmail.setFrom(from);
    gmail.setSubject(subject);
    gmail.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    gmail.addTo(to);
    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
    gmail.attach(attachment);
    } else {
    log.error(String.format("%s does not exist.", attachment));
    }
    gmail.send();
}
```

Comment: clarification - are you 100% sure that you actually hit the gmail.attach line? Also, have you tried creating your email with the line MultiPartEmail gmail = new HtmlEmail(); instead of MultiPartEmail gmail = new MultiPartEmail();? (Asking since the other working answers I've seen seem to use that instead.)

Comment: I have tried it as HtmlEmail() as well and the attachment still doesn't come through. I can also confirm that it does hit the gmail.attach(attachment) line and in the debugger in the Variables window (in Eclipse) the Name "attach() returned" shows a value of "HtmlEmail (id=72)", before it moves on to the gmail.send line and then sends the email. The email itself is received, just without an attachment. Is there anything else that would be preventing the actual attachement from sending?

Comment: I've dug a bit more - the only thing I've found so far is that you can call setDebug(true) on the gmail object to try and get more information. It's written to System.out when it writes

Comment: How do I go about verifying for certain that the file is attached before it sends?

Comment: if you're in Eclipse, you can check the object itself. Pathway is gmail.container.parts[0].dh.dataSource._file or gmail.emailBody.parts[0].dh.dataSource._file both showed me the file I'd attached. I was skipping the authentication and stuff, so for you there might be more than one part - you'll have to search there a bit

Answer (score 0):

remove: gmail.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).